# Similar regex, need to differentiate

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm practicing regex by building a credit card checker. Currently, everything works except for "Visa" and "Switch" payment networks.

Switch has several prefix numbers that begin with "4", and are 16, 18, or 19 digits in length.

Visa has a prefix of "4", and are of 16 or 19 digits long.

How do I differentiate the two via regex?

Here's my current regex:

```
var visa = /^4\d{3}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d/,
switch = /^(4903|4905|4936|6333|6759|564182|633110)\d+$/;
```

Comment: Within the parameters you've given, it doesn't seem like you can, a number starting with `4` and being 16 digits could match both of them ?

Comment: Please refer here: http://regular-expressions.mobi/creditcard.html

Comment: is there a way to set a bias towards the longer set?

Comment: Sure, just do that match first, and if it matches, don't do the second one etc. for instance a case/switch